# Hyperref, customizing the part command

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, books, parts

I am using the `hyperref` package in a book class document.

I have several parts which I want to refer to.

Here is my problem: I created a new command:

```
\newcommand{\partie}[1]{\hyperref[#1]{partie~\Roman{part}}}
```

Then assume that I have several parts:

```
\part{First one} \label{first}
\part{Second one} \label{second}
\part{Third one} \label{third}
```

so that when I call:

```
\partie{third}
```

I get

> partie III

The problem is that when I call `\partie{third}` in the first part of my document it produces:

> partie I

What can I do in order to fix that?

Thank you a lot.

Comment: Of course you will get `partie I` -- since `\Roman{part}` has the value `I` then. Your command is not well designed. You need a label to the relevant parts and not a manual specified number, as well as the hyperref anchor is most likely not existing!

Comment: Let me be more precise : when creating a part, e.g `\part{Third}` I put a label `\label{third}` but when calling it in the first part of my document with `\partie{third}` I get "Partie I"

Comment: Yes, of course, because you do not make use of the label at all.

Comment: Ok, so I think the problem is when I call `part` in my command, it appeals the current part. But in the pdf, the link is still correct. Chat should I change `part` with, in my definition ?

Comment: The link is alright if there's a label, but the expansion of `\Roman{part}` is wrong. Use     `\newcommand{\partie}[1]{\hyperref[#1]{partie~\ref*{#1}}}` instead!

Comment: In my point of view the `\partie` does add nothing what not `\cref` or `\autoref` can do already.

Comment: Thank you ! I think I will use clever ref in a near future :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the built-in cross-referencing system of LaTeX and its extensions by `hyperref` and `cleveref`.

As long there is no hypertarget anchor named `third` `\hyperref` will complain but print `partie I`, in the first part, since the part number is `1` there, so `\Roman{part}` expands to `I`.

Better method: Use `\cref{third}` or `\Cref{third}` with an label `third` which has been placed at the right position, with the `cleveref` option `nameinlink` the name of the referred unit will appear in the link as well.

There is `\autoref{third}` as well, which will print `Partie III`, i.e. with uppercase first character.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[french]{cleveref}

\newcommand{\partie}[1]{\hyperref[#1]{partie~\ref*{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\part{Un}

\cref{third} or \partie{third}

\part{Deux}

\part{Trois}\label{third}

Foo


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this nice example. However, I built a really long document (and customized preambule) with hyperref, so that I may use only hyperref. I will see if I can mix the two.

Comment: @M.LTA: You can always add `cleveref` ;-) And see the edit with a working solution for your needs

Answer (score 1):

The label name for the part number `#1` is already present in the macro definition of the question:

```
\newcommand{\partie}[1]{\hyperref[#1]{partie~\Roman{part}}}
```

Thus, the label can be referenced in macro `\partie` to get the part number.
A nested link is avoided by using the star form of `\ref`:

```
\newcommand{\partie}[1]{\hyperref[{#1}]{partie~\ref*{#1}}}
```

Of course, I assume, the part counter is properly set-up and `\thepart`
expands to `\Roman{part}`.